# How to wire up Micrometer with @WebMvcTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, resttemplate, spring-micrometer

Im trying to test a Spring Boot 2.3 `@Controller` that does metrics via Actuator/Prometheus with `@WebMvcTest`. Unfortunately this fails with a NPE, probably because the Micrometer/Prometheus classes are not present in test.

The controller does

```
Counter.builder(COUNTER_STATUS)
        .description(DESCRIPTION_STATUS)
        .tags(TAG_ACCOUNT, String.valueOf(accountId), TAG_STATUS, String.valueOf(status))
        .register(registry)
        .increment();
```

The test has

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(HerodotusController.class)

  @MockBean(MeterRegistry.class)
  private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
```

This fails with an NPE at the line of `Counter`...; I believe because at test runtime there's no implementation of that interface (at runtime it's implemented by `io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus`).

How can I get an implementation of the Micrometer interface into my test so that it passes?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The problem is the mocked `MeterRegistry`.

The NPE happens here:

```
public Counter register(MeterRegistry registry) {
  return registry.counter(new Meter.Id(name, tags, baseUnit, description, Type.COUNTER));
}
```

The solution is to not *mock* the `MeterRegistry` but instead provide one via

```
@TestConfiguration
static class AdditionalConfig {
  @Bean
  public MeterRegistry registry() {
    return new SimpleMeterRegistry();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to make bean MeterRegistry as Primary for overriding original bean