# MeterRegistry counter test case failing

Tags: spring-boot, junit, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I have implemented Micrometer Prometheus counter in my service by injecting `MeterRegistry` and incrementing the count as shown below, and I have written a test case as well, but when I am running the test case, I am getting:

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.counter(String,
> String[])" because "this.meterRegistry" is null".

Service file:

```java
@Autowired
private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
    
public void counterIncrement() { 
    meterRegistry.counter("test_count").increment();
}
```

Test case file:

```java
@MockBean
private MeterRegistry registry;
     
@Test
void testCounter() {
    //  invoking counterIncrement();
}
```

Comment: You can instantiate a `SimpleMeterRegistry` for tests.

Comment: solved by mocking the bean in the test!

Answer (score 6):

You can test metrics without Mockito using [SimpleMeterRegistry](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/latest/io/micrometer/core/instrument/simple/SimpleMeterRegistry.html)

```java
  @Test
  void testCounter() {
    var meterRegistry = new SimpleMeterRegistry();
    Metrics.addRegistry(meterRegistry);

    //  invoke counterIncrement();

    var actual = meterRegistry.counter("test_count").count();
    
    assertEquals(1.0d, actual);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

How do you create your class under test?
Since the `registry` is never instantiated, something seems up with how you setup your test.

Check that you are using the `@MockBean` in the correct way. This will replace the bean in the application context and if you do not spin up a spring context in your test, it will not work. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200720/difference-between-mock-mockbean-and-mockito-mock) post for more info.

A different approach would be to use `@Mock` and inject the registry in the constructor, example:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

  @Mock
  private MeterRegistry registry;

  private MyService myService;

  @BeforeEach
  void setup() {
    myService = new MyService(registry);
  }

  @Test
  void testCounter() {
    var counter = mock(Counter.class);
    given(registry.counter(any(String.class))).willReturn(counter);
    myService.counterIncrement();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which junit version you are using you need to add the annotation to your test class. Junit 5: `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`  or for Junit 4: `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the test and the service there are several ways to deal with the missing MeterRegistry.

1. If you use a spring context in your test, try to [use a test configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64660845/11934850) to create the MeterRegistry bean.
2. If your test uses some Mock framework, you could mock the MeterRegistry as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72373585/11934850) by by @Hans-Christian.
3. If you simply make the member meterRegistry non-private. You could set it to a SimpleMeterRegistry in some setup method, anotated with `@BeforeEach` as suggested by @checketts [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72361158/meterregistry-counter-test-case-failing#comment127852506_72361158).
4. If mocking the meter registry gets complicated, you could easily build and use some factory that provides the registry and mock this factory. A very easy factory will do, e.g. a spring `@Component` with an autowired MeterRegistry and some public getter for the factory.
5. You could use the factory method pattern [as described in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to get the MeterRegistry, overwrite  the factory method in a subclass of your service and use this subclass in the test. (Note that the gang of four did use a [static factory method](https://www.gofpatterns.com/creational/patterns/factory-method-pattern.php), you'll need a non-static method.)

I favour solution 3 but would use solution 1 whenever appropriate. I've added solutions 4 and 5 just because there might be some additional reasons and special cases that make these solutions a good choice. If so, I prefer 4 over 5.